# join Not working in spark 1.5.2 with more than 5 data frame

Tags: mysql, scala, join, apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to do  more joins on multiple tables with pyspark,

and then I want to partition by date
my tables:

my setup is as follows:
    10GO  MEMORY for driver 
    10 workers with 5 cores and 10G Memory 
    yarn-customer

Table = 700 MO

Table2 = 1GB

Table 3 = 3Go

Table4 = 12

Table 4 go

table5 =6go

I tried

```
sqlcontext.sql ("select * from Tab1 left join tab2 is tab1.numcnt =      

tab2.numcnt  left join tab3 is tab1.numcnt = tab3.numcnt
left join TAB4 is tab1.numcnt = tab4.numcnt
")
```

when I use this query she takes a crazy time

I also tried the data frame methods:

```
df = join df_tab1.join (df_tab2, df_tab.NUMCNT df_tab2.NUMCNT == 'left_outer')

 dfjoin.join (df_tab3, df_join.NUMCNT df_tab3.NUMCNT == 'left_outer')
```

same problem 24 hours of treatment without result

if you can advise me how to properly join these thank you in advance

Comment: I can't make sense of your code. Would you mind transforming that into something valid, so your intent becomes a little bit clearer? You'll have a way greater chance of getting help, if you provide a minmal example that shows what you're trying to do.

Comment: thank you karlson, but my question is  simple
i want make more than one join but when i try with pyspark ,
with successive join , it either with (sqlcontext.sql) or (df.join-df2)
I have no results  after 24 hours of processing
why ?

Comment: But please take a look at your question. The lines in your last example aren't proper python statements. If you'd provide your actual code,  people might suggest how to improve on that.

Comment: my question is about the join just I do not understand:
tab1 = sqlcontext.read.parquet ('tab1) 700 MO
tab2 sqlcontext.read.parquet = ('tab2) 1GB
tab1 = sqlcontext.read.parquet ('tab1) 3Go
....
TAB5 sqlcontext.read.parquet = ('TAB5) 12 GO
after I just want to do a join that's all.
But the question: why? it takes an eternity without result.
may be you have to put the tables in the cache?
may be we should stop the shuffl .....

Comment: There is an "edit" button below you're question. Please use it to fix your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache all the tables which you are joining before performing the join. I would recommend to cache them, do a count on them and then perform join. I faced similar issue too but after performing join on cached tables, runtime gets significantly reduced.